# Base 256 array addition Recursively

Tags: c#, recursion

Is there any way to improve `private byte[] RecursiveAdd(byte[] f, byte[] s, int index, byte[] result, bool carry = false)` method? The method signature is too long and I want to stick with recursion so no loops.

```
   public class Base256Calculator : IBase256Calculator
    {
        public byte[] Add(byte[] f, byte[] s)
        {
            byte[] result = new byte[f.Length];
            return RecursiveAdd(f, s, f.Length - 1, result);
        }

        private byte[] RecursiveAdd(byte[] f, byte[] s, int index, byte[] result, bool carry = false)
        {
            if (index < 0)
            {
                if (carry)
                {
                    result[0] = Convert.ToByte("1" + result[0]);
                }
                return result;
            }

            ushort sum = (ushort)(f[index] + s[index] + (carry ? 1 : 0));
            carry = sum / 256 == 1;
            result[index] = (byte)(sum % 256);
            return RecursiveAdd(f, s, --index, result, carry);
        }
    }
```

For the completeness I have posted the usage

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {

         byte[] arr1 = { 90, 100 };
         byte[] arr2 = { 255, 250 };

         IBase256Calculator c = new Base256Calculator();
         byte[] result = c.Add(arr1, arr2);
 }
```

Comment: Even a too long method signature is no excuse for naming your variables `f` and `s` instead of `first` and `second`.

Comment: @RolandIllig - Point taken. Anything else inside the method that can be improved?

Comment: @t3chb0t - To ask a follow up question should i post a new question and put a link to this one? I have modified the code and would like to run through this community before finalising it - Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before posting your code here, you should properly test it. Even your given example gives the wrong result (190, 94) instead of the correct one (1, 90, 94).

The `carry` parameter should be of type `byte`, since you use it like this.

The signature of the private method has to be this long because you use recursion. With a simple `while` loop, you would need no extra variable. But you said you want recursion, so there is no workaround.

`--index` should be `index - 1` instead, since you don't need the modified value in the calling method. In general, don't modify the parameters. This makes stepping through the code easier.

The `Add` function should also work if the two given numbers have different length.

Comment: Are you sure it should be `1, 90, 94` and not `185, 255, 255` or do I get it entirely wrong?

Comment: Thanks for identifying the bug, i was under impression that it should be 190,94. @t3chb0t Could you please elaborate how you reached to 185, 255, 255?

Comment: @YawarMurtaza I understand it as `90, 100` + `255, 250` = `100+250=255` carry 95, then `90+255+95=255` carry 185 = `185, 255, 255`

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is a bad idea to use default parameter value for private methods. Default argument is an easy way to forget about parameter and get incorrect behavior. But it is just my opinion, not the rule.

---

You should declare a constant for `256`:

```
private const int Base = 256;
```

---

If you have division and remainder calculation of the same numbers, you can use `Math.DivRem` method:

```
carry = Math.DivRem(sum, Base, out var remainder) == 1;
result[index] = (byte)remainder;
```

Comment: +1 - Good suggestions! 
If the parameter bool carry = false is not set to its default value then it will become mandatory for the calling method Add to pass it in which seems to be awkward at that point - why client code should care about a bool variable named carry.

Comment: `carry` parameter exists only in private method, it is not visible for a user of your public API so I don't see any problems to make it mandatory :) But is is completely up for you. As for me I try to avoid optional parameters in private API. It helps me to be more focused when I call a method and prevents issues.

Comment: I don't like default parameters either. Usually I create another overload that uses some default value for some parameters if I want to make them optional. I think this is a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Linq (no loops) instead of explicit recursion, something like this. Assuming both arrays are of the same length. The 'reverse' may have an impact on large arrays.

```
    int carry = 0;

    var result =
        Enumerable.Zip(
            arr1.Reverse(),
            arr2.Reverse(),
            (v1, v2) =>
                {
                    var sum = v1 + v2 + carry;

                    carry = sum / 256;

                    return (byte)(sum % 256);
                })
        .ToArray() // flush to get the carry value
        .Concat(
            Enumerable.Repeat((byte)1, carry))
        .Reverse();
}
```